# @Inherited annotation is not being inherited

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations

I have a `SubClass` and a `SuperClass`, as well as an annotation `DocAnnotation`. I need a call to `SubClass.foo()` to get all class annotations from `SubClass` and `SuperClass`. The classes are defined like this:

## SuperClass

```
package Code

import Annotations.DocAnnotation;
import java.util.Arrays;

@DocAnnotation("Super Annotation")
public class SuperClass {

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.getClass().getAnnotations()));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(this.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotations()));
    }
}
```

## SubClass

```
package Code;

import Annotations.DocAnnotation;

@DocAnnotation("Sub Annotation")
public class SubClass extends SuperClass{
}
```

## DocAnnotation

```
package Annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Repeatable;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;

@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(DocAnnotations.class)
public @interface DocAnnotation {
    String value();
}
```

Running SubClass.foo I expect to see both `"Super Annotation"` and `"Sub Annotation"` but instead I see only `[@Annotations.DocAnnotation(value=Sub Annotation)]`. Am I misunderstanding what @inherited does, or am I doing something incorrectly?

---

Edit:

After adding the annotation `@DocAnnotation("Super Annotation")` to `SubClass` (that's the same one as in `SuperClass`) it actually shows up twice, once for its use in `SubClass` and once for its use in `SuperClass`! Now I'm nearly certain I'm misunderstanding something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the intended behavior, or at least it's specified to work this way ([doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html)):

> If [...] the user queries the annotation type on a class declaration, **and the class declaration has no annotation for this type**, then the class's superclass will automatically be queried for the annotation type.

In other words, since `SubClass` is already annotated with `@DocAnnotation`, the superclass is not queried.

On further inspection, the behavior seems a bit weird, though, especially after experimenting with presence of the containing annotation type. I came up with the following example which illustrates this ([link](https://ideone.com/nN5GMB)):

```
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import java.util.*;

@Inherited
@Repeatable(Container.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Ann {
    String value();
}

@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@interface Container {
    Ann[] value();
}

// Basic case. Result is that
// only @Ann("2") is present on
// ExhibitASub.
@Ann("1")
class ExhibitASuper {
}
@Ann("2")
class ExhibitASub extends ExhibitASuper {
}

// Because this case results in the
// @Container being present on ExhibitBSuper,
// rather than @Ann, all three annotations
// end up appearing on ExhibitBSub.
@Ann("1")
@Ann("2")
class ExhibitBSuper {
}
@Ann("3")
class ExhibitBSub extends ExhibitBSuper {
}

// Similar to the preceding case, by
// forcing the use of @Container, both
// annotations are present on ExhibitCSub.
@Container(@Ann("1"))
class ExhibitCSuper {
}
@Ann("2")
class ExhibitCSub extends ExhibitCSuper {
}

// Yet when we force both to use @Container,
// only @Container(@Ann("2")) is present on
// ExhibitDSub.
@Container(@Ann("1"))
class ExhibitDSuper {
}
@Container(@Ann("2"))
class ExhibitDSub extends ExhibitDSuper {
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Class<?> cls : Arrays.asList(ExhibitASub.class,
                                          ExhibitBSub.class,
                                          ExhibitCSub.class,
                                          ExhibitDSub.class)) {
            System.out.printf("%s:%n", cls);
            for (Annotation ann : cls.getAnnotations()) {
                System.out.printf("    %s%n", ann);
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

The output of which is as follows:

```
class ExhibitASub:
    @Ann(value=2)

class ExhibitBSub:
    @Container(value=[@Ann(value=1), @Ann(value=2)])
    @Ann(value=3)

class ExhibitCSub:
    @Container(value=[@Ann(value=1)])
    @Ann(value=2)

class ExhibitDSub:
    @Container(value=[@Ann(value=2)])
```

Note that for B and C we see both the annotations on the superclass and subclass. Presumably this is because (in a strict sense) the annotation present on the superclass is of a different type than the annotation present on the subclass. Note that for D we return to only seeing the subclass annotation because both classes use the container type.

Using the containing annotation type explicitly could be a workaround for some cases, but it's not a general solution because of case D.

I might file a bug report for this tomorrow since this seems pretty undesirable. Since `@Inherited` predates `@Repeatable`, this behavior could be from previous versions where this situation couldn't occur.

Comment: I totally forgot about the container annotation! That was really throwing me for a loop... Do you know if the behavior I'm describing is possible? I could directly query all classes that the subclass extends, but that seems like ugly code. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't think so. Another solution could be to abandon annotations altogether and use an interface. I can't really say if that's better for your case, but it could work since you're annotating the class.

Comment: I think I'm going to have to stick to annotations, but thanks! If you do end up submitting a bug report, please post a link to it here. I'd be interested to know whether Oracle expects this behavior as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this annotation wrong. The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) clearly states:

> Indicates that an annotation type is automatically inherited. If an Inherited meta-annotation is present on an annotation type declaration, and the user queries the annotation type on a class declaration, and the class declaration has no annotation for this type, then the class's superclass will automatically be queried for the annotation type.

In other words: if you query the subclass, then you would find the *super class* being annotated. But this thing is **not** meant for *inheritance* in the "OO sense". If you want to see *both* annotations, you have to write code that checks *each* class in the class inheritance tree manually.